# Django Tables2 displays incorrect truth values

Tags: django, django-tables2

I'm having a pretty frustrating problem with Django 1.7 and Django-Tables2 (0.15.0).

My model:

```
class Xuser(TimeStampedModel):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=6, primary_key=True)
    moniker = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    citizenship = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    employee_type = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
    mail = models.EmailField(max_length=32)
    open_account_authorized = models.BooleanField(choices=YES_NO, default=None)
    open_account_enabled = models.BooleanField(choices=YES_NO, default=None)  
    root_authorized = models.BooleanField(choices=YES_NO, default=None)
```

From forms.py:

```
class AdminXuserTable(tables.Table):
    number = tables.LinkColumn('accountadmindetail', args=[tables.A('number')])

    class Meta:
        model = Xuser
        attrs = {"class": "adminsearchresults"}
        fields = ('number', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'open_account_authorized', 'open_account_enabled',
              'root_authorized', )
```

From views.py:

```
def accountadmin(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            searchtype = request.POST.get('search')
            value = request.POST.get('value')

            xusers = Xuser.objects.all()
            if searchtype == 'number':
                results = xusers.filter(number__startswith=value)
            elif searchtype == 'group':
                results = xusers.filter(department__contains=value)
            elif searchtype == 'first':
                results = xusers.filter(first_name__contains=value)
            elif searchtype == 'last':
                results = xusers.filter(last_name__contains=value)
            elif searchtype == 'moniker':
                results = xusers.filter(moniker__contains=value)
            else:
                messages.error(request, ERRMSG_NO_POST)
                results = None

            if results:
                resultstable = AdminXuserTable(results)
            else:
                resultstable = None

        except IndexError:
            messages.error(request, ERRMSG_NO_POST)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('error'))
    else:
        resultstable = None

    return render_to_response('includes/accountadmin.html',
                              {"resultstable": resultstable, },
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The problem that I am having is that whether the search returns 1 result or a dozen in the table, all of the Boolean values are shown as True (check mark), regardless of what they are in the database.

I don't know if it is relevant but my project began as a Django 1.6 and I migrated it over to Django 1.7 pretty late in the game.  Everything is working fine except for this.  Boolean values are stored in my database as 't' or 'f'.  Any ideas?

Comment: What you want to display for Boolean field?

Comment: When this was all working, columns that had a True value would show a ✓ and columns that contained a False value showed an ✗.  Something has happened recently that causes all values to show as ✓ even when they are False.  I have no idea how to troubleshoot this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i finally figured it out.  The issue was actually with my `choices` option.  This is what i had my `choices` defined as:

```
YES_NO = (
    (True, 'Yes'),
    (False, 'No'),
)
```

I started hacking through the `django-tables2/columns/booleancolumn.py` code.  When i set the `render` function to just return the value given to it, i realized that the value was "Yes" or "No".  Since the code converts these values with `bool()` it was always returning `True`.

Without some customization i don't think Django-Tables2 can handle "choices" on a `BooleanField`.